# problem with passwords using sha256

Tags: php, mysql

I am playing around with password encryptions and i am having some trouble when I write the password into database and when I ry to log in to the page.

When I insert the password:

```
$pword = "huuhaa";
$uname = "huuhaa";

$pword = hash('sha256' ,'$pword');
    $insuser="INSERT INTO words(username,password) VALUES('$uname','$pword') ";

$insresult=mysql_query($insuser);
```

In the log in:

```
$myusername= 'huuhaa';

$mypassword = 'huuhaa';


$mypasswordCRYPTED = hash('sha256' ,'$mypassword');


$sql="SELECT userid FROM words WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypasswordCRYPTED'";
```

LOG IN:

the value in database is different from the value in login eg. $pword in database: e5f252f... And in log in: $mypasswordCRYPTED = as89dw....

Would someone please explain this to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you want:

```
$pword = hash('sha256', $pword);
```

and

```
$mypasswordCRYPTED = hash('sha256', $mypassword);
```

i.e. the variable rather than the string `'$pword'`? It would have worked with `"$pword"` using double quotes to get PHP to perform string interpolation, but it's a lot clearer just to use the variable itself as the function argument.

So basically you were comparing the hashes of the string '$pword' and '$mypassword' - which unsurprisingly aren't the same :)

Comment: Damn jon, you're 2 seconds faster :( Good job

Comment: PHP interpolates in double-quoted strings, not single-quoted ones. That string is literally "$pword"

Comment: @Phil: Thanks. Will update. (It's obviously clearer not to bother with interpolation anyway.)

Comment: @genesis Jon actually answered 2 seconds after the question was posted. He was just holding off for suspense ;-)

Comment: @Phil: No. That's lie. He answered it 2 seconds BEFORE question was posted. But this answer just shows the turth of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes) post :( ;)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$pword = hash('sha256' ,'$pword');
```

to

```
$pword = hash('sha256' ,$pword);
```

because that first one recognizes your password as `$pword`

and the same thing with second variable

```
$mypasswordCRYPTED = hash('sha256' ,'$mypassword');
```

to

```
$mypasswordCRYPTED = hash('sha256' ,$mypassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hashing the string `'$mypassword'`, try changing it to `$mypassword` and changing `'$pword'` to `$pword`.